# carries in and out of most significant bits in binary addition

Tags: math, binary, overflow

I have this binary addition problem,

```
  01010  
+ 11011
```

= 100101 need a 5 bit answer so drop the 1 so 00101 since overflow has occurerd.

However it then asks,

What's value of the carry in to the most significant bit?

What's value of the carry out of the most significant bit?

I assumed that these were both 1, can anyone clarify this,

I got the answer one by doing the arithmetic and looking at the carries in and out of the Most Significant Bit... is this correct ?

Thanks in advance for any help/clarification,

Sim

Comment: possible duplicate of [Carries in and out of significant bits in binary addition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245174/carries-in-and-out-of-significant-bits-in-binary-addition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However it then asks,

What is 'it'?

Anyway, to answer your question, yes it seems correct. The MSB (Most Significant Bit) of both operands are respectively 0 and 1.

The carry in (coming from the sum of all the previous bits) is 1, and the carry out is thus equal to:

- 0 (MSB first operand) + 1 (MSB second operand) + 1 (carry in) = 1, as you correctly pointed out.

Comment: Does it answer your question?